# Работа с проектом на локальном сервере

Tags: хостинг, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо осуществлять работу с проектом на локальном сервере, а после тестов заливать на хост без изменений конекшенов к базе данных и т.д. подскажите как это осуществить? Т.е. у меня на локальном, разумеется, `localhost`, а на хосте например `tret44566` и при заливании на продакшн это постоянно нужно менять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно вводят два или несколько окружений на уровне приложения, в зависимости от того, на каком сервере находится приложение оно самостоятельно выбирает набор настроек. Как правило, это реализуется через переменные окружения, например, можно завести переменную окружения `APP_HOST`.

**nginx**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_param APP_HOST prod; 
    ...
}
```

**apache**

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
   ...
   SetEnv APP_HOST prod
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

В приложении можно читать переменную окружения и в зависимости от того, в какое значение она выставлена назначать тот или иной набор параметров (для этого предназначена функция `getenv()`, над которой в разных языках могут быть свои обертки, следует уточнять по каждому из языков). При помощи переменных окружения можно задавать критическую информацию, например, пароли, чтобы они не присутствовали в коде и вообще не покидали сервер для которого они предназначены.